# What is the computational model of ICON and SNOBOL

Tags: computation

I try to found computation model of programming languages like Icon and Snobol but i can't found the information about these programming languages...!
I want know What the computational model of ICON and SNOBOL is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snobol is functional and logic model (see the right side of this page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SNOBOL) and Icon support Imperative model.